# My laptop's keyboard sometimes does not respond

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard

I have **Acer Aspire E15 E5-571** laptop and it runs **MS Windows 8.1 OS**. Sometimes, when I type letter 'a' on the keyboard it does not appear on the screen. For example, when I type the first part of my email, the letter does not appear on display, although when I type the top level domain, the 'gmail.com' part, it appears on the screen. What might be the problem? P.S., Caps Lock does not respond too, sometimes.

P.S., lately I have had disassembled my laptop to figure out something from its architecture; it involved disconnecting keyboard (cable) from the system-board. After that this typing problem starts appearing. Although the rest keyboard appears to be working.
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Dirt/dust in the way? Tried vacuum / compressed air?

Comment: Yet, it's quite new laptop, I bought it in September 2014; it appears that no dust appears in. Thus, I did not try vacuum. Nonetheless it displays the 'a' letter when I'm typing now, for some reasons.

Comment: If it's new enough, and bought from a good store, I'd be tempted to use the warranty. But if it's "fixed" now, maybe it was just dirty. Compressed air dusting is good cleaning, with *gentle* air, like a commercial can, don't try 125psi or anything